# flask with bootstrap4, not show modal, use CDN works well

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4

I use flask to push html to web, and use bs4 in html.
When I use bs4, `modal`, I find if the html passthrough flask, `modal` not working at all. I can only use CDN. Below only first one works well.

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js</script>
<script src="../static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

[BS4 Modal Sample](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h)

As well as bs4.css.

Any sugguestion?

Comment: What problem are you having ? Just add dependencies for bootstrap from CDN. From that example you need to add JQuery, popper.js, bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css .

Comment: @DinkoPehar if I use local bs4.css, bs4.js on flask server, not use CDN, bs4 is not working at all.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a folder named 'static' in the same folder than your Flask server script. The 'static' folder contains the bootstrap folder. The line `<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>` will then work.

Comment: static folder has been exist in app folder, other static files load well on web.